# How to move my navigation (which is on top of an image) via animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am in the process of designing my website (I am a graphic designer). My navigation is placed on top of an image (the image is animated via flash). It is centered on my homepage, which contains nothing but my navigation and a small banner; it's very simplistic. I want my navigation (from here on out, navigation means the actual nav and the image underneath it) to slide from the center to the left when a link is clicked, which would allow my actual content to show. I cannot use flash for this animation. I have been searching and can't find anything similar enough for me to even remotely understand. Looking at other people's code to solve your code questions doesn't always work for me.

What can I do to animate this smoothly? I have some javascript/java knowledge, and a decent amount of HTML/CSS. I have been searching for hours and am at my wits end. I obviously don't have any code to share because I have no idea where to start. Any resource or explanation would be so useful.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery or looking at jQuery examples?

Comment: I have not tried using anything, I have no idea where to start. I have seen examples of things that are kind of similar, but I haven't found anything that has helped me get started, or even lead me to understand where to begin. I have been searching and nothing seems to fit what I want to do. There's always some condition to their question or example that complicates things too much.

Comment: this was probably the closest thing I found that is similar to what I want to do, but there's no breakdown of what does what, and it's all very confusing. it's just raw code. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/94Ny6/)

Comment: I added some comments that may be helpful: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Ny6/1/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that. I think I'm going to look further into more simplistic CSS animations at this point, but I will be favoriting this link for later reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Okay I made you a quick demo to give you an idea of what to do. This is using css transitions as well as jQuery for the click events. All I am doing is adding and removing class, I then let css do the effects for me.

css:

```
.mainNav {
    width: 516px;
    height: 516px;
    background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8357/8413355900_c5cce4b825_o.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: right 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: right 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 1s ease;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.nav li').on('click', function() {
   var src = $(this).attr('id'); // This variable is grabbing the clicked elements id to later be combined with a selector to make this flexible

    $('.mainNav').addClass('active');
    $('.bodyCont').removeClass('active');
    $('#p-' + src).addClass('active');

    $('#home').click(function(){
      $('.mainNav').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo, remove show in url to view code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/P37R4/3/show/)

Since there is no code as you stated the best I can do is suggest certain routes to go.

Of course you can use javascript/jQuery to animate it to your liking but lets try and identify the needs you have.

1. What browsers are you supporting
2. What is your targeted audience
3. Are you concerned about load time
4. How much time is needed.

After analyzing those questions you can better prepare yourself for what to do.

---

Now for some suggestions,

You have a good range of options you can use but I will suggest what I believe is the best route. The two options I have for you is to use jQuery or css animations.

jQuery:

Very flexible and can easily achieve this result if you know what to do. Don't need to worry about old browsers as much and shouldn't be to much of a load difference. (especially if you are using flash which I highly recommend to rethink that)

css animations:

These, in my eyes, are much easier to get going and can be incredibly flexible. It also resembles flash a little bit by the use of `keyframes` and is easier to write then jQuery. The strongest downside to them is old browser support since these are still fairly new.

Comment: 1. I would like to support as many browsers as possible. 
2.My targeted audience isn't necessarily particular, it's anyone who's interested in my graphic design/web design, and wants to know more. 
3.The load time is sort of here and there. I don't want it to take forever, but a little time won't kill anyone. 
4.I have quite a few weeks until this must be completed. I just want to get it going as fast as I can.

Comment: as for your suggestions, I am trying to avoid flash because it is not compatible with any apple product; iphones, ipads, safari..it won't work. The mobile community, whether it be on tablets or their phones, creates a lot more traffic than someone on a desktop. I want it to be accessible to these people. For this reason I've decided to avoid flash for my navigation movement. I would like to use it, but think it's best to avoid it (based on my opinion and my instructors' experiences).

Comment: I would say if possible go with CSS animations. They are cleaner & faster than jquery.

Comment: @Nilesh I like css animations because like you said they are easier and in my eyes a lot better.

Comment: @rachrayann I have added a demo to give you a starting place, refer to my updated answer!

Comment: Thank you for that demo, it looks very useful to what I'd like to do, and I greatly appreciate it! I will be referencing it as well!

Comment: I am glad I could have been of help, is this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: Pretty much. I just wanted some sort of basis so I could build from there and not feel totally clueless. This will be of great use to me, as well as some other resources that were given to me here. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome and best of luck in your design mate!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use CSS transitions.  I'm going to assume that your nav elements are wrapped in a nav tag in the example below:

Firstly, add this to your css on the nav element:

```
transition:left 1s;
```

The duration can be changed and you can add ease in or ease out or both (see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions))

Then, add an event listener to the link to call this javascript function:

```
function moveLeft(){
    document.getElementById('nav').style.left = '0px';
}
```

This should move the nav element over to the left.  You might need to change what css property you are transitioning depending on how you have positioned your element.  The article I linked to above should outline the css properties that can be transitioned (they link to a list).

I hope this helps.
NOTE: I haven't tested this code as I don't know how your page is configured.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Thank you. This looks much more palatable for me at this moment. I am more than willing to learn more about jQuery and javascript (and I am, I'm currently taking an additional class to do so), it is just complicated to look at and attempt to understand certain parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you play with AngularJS animation. It performs very well with CSS transitions.

I feel from your question that animating the `ngView` directive is what you need.

Here is a sweet [tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You sound like somebody new to coding, so first let me say a hardy hello! StackOverflow is great for stuff like this.

If I were you, don't start off moving elements on a webpage. Concentrate on nailing the box model, which is the layout of your page. I'd recommend you investigate the CSS property 'display', as it controls how most of your page will be laid out.

A couple good sources I always check out - the Mozilla Development Network (MDN) and css-tricks.com (Chris Coyers site):

- http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

I like putting colored backgrounds on my structural elements before doing any style / movement. Codepen.io is a nice site, where you can just make snippets of code to test stuff:

- http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/LxuqB

Now, if you really want to animate elements on your website, you will need a combination of jQuery as mentioned and probably some CSS3 transition / animate properties. Again, CSS Tricks is a good place to start - excellent code samples there:

- http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Next steps for you: layout the site using structural CSS and the necessary HTML, post those items into your question above and then ask me and others exactly how we would animate that element - you'll get a much more specific response that way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I am much further along in coding than you seem to believe. I've been building and designing websites for over a year now and am a full-time student. In this particular situation I've had a difficult time finding the right place to start because everyone's situation is different. My html and css is already laid out for my page and configured. I just wanted someone to point me as to where to start.